# Distinguish between entering and exiting a region with Power Automate location trigger

Tags: triggers, location, geofencing, power-automate

When using the "When I enter or exit an area" trigger in Power Automate, how do I check to see if I'm entering or exiting? There is no output value that indicates it.

[image]

Answer (score 1):

There is a hidden attribute of the trigger output body called `transitionType`.

- **Entering** area has `transitionType = 1`
- **Exiting** area has `transitionType = 2`

Use an expression to access the value:

[image]